# Is opencl known to generate corrupt code?

Tags: macos, opengl, clang, opencl, llvm

I have a small opencl kernel that writes to a shared GL texture. I have separated different stages of the computation into several functions. Every function gets a pointer to the final color and passes this along if needed. If you look at the code fragment you see a line that is called "UNREACHABLE". For some reason it does get executed. What ever color I put in there appears in the final image. How is that possible?

If I duplicate the same code block below that does not happen. Only for the first one. :(

To make things even funnier, if I change the code above (e.g. add another multiplication) the UNREACHABLE line gets executed at random.

Therefore my questions: Is this a compiler bug? Do I exhaust a certain memory or register budged that I should be aware of? Are OpenCL compilers buggy in general?

```
void sample(float4 *color) {
    ...
    float4 r_color = get_color(...);
    float factor = r_color.w + (*color).w - 1.0f;

    r_color = r_color * ((r_color.w - factor) / r_color.w);

    *color += r_color;
    if(color->w >= 1.0f) {
      if(color->w <= 0.0f) {
        (*color) = (float4)(0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f); //UNREACHABLE?
        return;
      }
    }
    ...
}
...
__kernel void render(
    __write_only image2d_t output_buffer,
    int width,
    int height
) {
    uint screen_x = get_global_id(0);
    uint screen_y = get_global_id(1);

    float4 color = (float4)(0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f);

    sample(&color);

    write_imagef(output_buffer, (int2)(screen_x, screen_y), color);
}
```

My Platform:

Apple

- Intel(R) Core(TM) i5-2415M CPU @ 2.30GHz

selected device has extensions: cl_APPLE_SetMemObjectDestructor cl_APPLE_ContextLoggingFunctions cl_APPLE_clut cl_APPLE_query_kernel_names cl_APPLE_gl_sharing cl_khr_gl_event cl_khr_fp64 cl_khr_global_int32_base_atomics cl_khr_global_int32_extended_atomics cl_khr_local_int32_base_atomics cl_khr_local_int32_extended_atomics cl_khr_byte_addressable_store cl_khr_int64_base_atomics cl_khr_int64_extended_atomics cl_khr_3d_image_writes cl_khr_image2d_from_buffer cl_APPLE_fp64_basic_ops cl_APPLE_fixed_alpha_channel_orders cl_APPLE_biased_fixed_point_image_formats cl_APPLE_command_queue_priority

**[Edit]**

After observing the values I get during the calculation I am thinking r_color.w being exactly 0.0f after get_color may cause the problem. I am still looking for a definite statement that says comparing a NaN is not defined or is always true or something.

Also "Is opencl known to generate corrupt code?" has the invisible postfix "or what am I missing".

I used to work with embedded systems where the vendor would provide their own proprietary compilers, which in turn were known to break your code. So I want to get this off the table if possible. I suspect that clang would not do that. But you never know.

Comment: OpenCL compilers are buggy as they're software :) Try your code on both a CPU and GPU device and see what happens.

Comment: CPU and GPU behave similar. I think I found the issue. A mistake in get_color caused r_color.w to be always zero. Apparently comparing a NaN to something is not such a good idea.